# How to persist the time and score using shared preferences

Tags: android, arraylist, sharedpreferences

I having developing simple application, which has just like game. When I have finished game the gave over page display, which as **time** and **score**. Now if i want to play that game again and again. How to store that previous all time and score and current finished.

I want to display, all time and score in to the list according to high to low score, after score button was clicked.

I have done shared preferences in gaveover page and that value get from score page. but why not display when i play third time. second time it is ok. third time and so on.. just replacing upward . I don't have enough idea, how to store that all information in to array and display on list. But I have try to use map, but getting not more idea.

I want to display this type of format in to the score page:

> Time  ..............            Score
>
> 1:10  ..............            175
>
> 2:05 ..............             145
>
> 1:15 ..............             110
>
> 2:50 ...............             90

Here I have just started little code but not complete and better,

**GaveOver.Java**

```
Where just diplay socre , time and mistakes after finish game.
```

**Score.Java**

```
public class Scores extends Activity {
private static String strTime;
private static int intScore;
public static SharedPreferences settings;
public static final String MY_PREFS_NAME = "PrefName";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ImageView back, reset, score_home;
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.score);

    // lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    getValuesFromGaveOver();

    SharedPreferences pref = this.getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, 0);
    String data=pref.getString("DATA", "Nothing");
    Log.i("horror", "DATA "+data);      
}
private void getValuesFromGaveOver() {
    SharedPreferences pref = this.getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, 0);
    strTime = pref.getString(TIME, "n/a");
    intScore = pref.getInt(SCORE, -1);
    Log.i("horror", "From Gave Over  "+"Time="+strTime+"   "+"Score="+intScore);
}
@Override
protected void onStop() {
            super.onStop();
    SharedPreferences pref = this.getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, 0);
    strTime = pref.getString(TIME, "");
    intScore = pref.getInt(SCORE, -1);

    savePreferences(intScore, strTime);

}

private void savePreferences(int s, String t) {
    SharedPreferences sPref = this.getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = sPref.edit();
    edit.putString("DATA", strTime+" "+intScore);
      edit.commit();
}
}
```

please give me the good suggestion, how  to do it?

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way would be to use sqlite databases.

Using `SharedPreferences` is much easier, especially for beginners.
You could do it like that: You save a 3rd item, the actual entry count as `SharedPreference`.
Everytime you save a new entry you increment this counter.
Then you append the current counter number to the TIME and SCORE keys.

```
// Saves a new entry | Attention: code not tested!
save(int score, int time){
 SharedPreference pref = ...
 SharedPreference.Editor editor = ...

 int newEntryID = pref.getInt("numEntries", 0) + 1;

 editor.setInt("numEntries", newEntryID);
 editor.setInt("score" + newEntryID, score);
 editor.setString("time" + newEntryID, time); 
 editor.commit();
}
```

Assuming "score" is the SharedPreference-Key for SCORE and same for the time.

Reading would be of the same scheme.

```
for(int i=0; i<numEntries; ++i){
  pref.getInt("score" + i, 0);
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

using the shared preference you can store both,

1) first you have to store time, once this is done you have to store score mapped on the given time,

you are doing this way,
edit.putString("DATA", strTime+" "+intScore);

But you can take different approach if you have only one player playing at one time,
edit.putString("TIME", strTime);
edit.putString(strTime, strScore);

1:10 .............. 175
So here first you mapped your time with TIME and then you mapped score 175 with 1:10

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

Good idea would be to define Java bean holding score ( say with 2 Fields, time in seconds  / points / maybe date  / name / whatrever else fields you like to store). You  can easily do following with them:

- sort in a list and limit their amount ( you do not like to have 10000 of score entries,  100 will be anough )
- marshall this list to / from JSON ( Shameless self advertising: https://github.com/ko5tik/jsonserializer  )
- store JSON in a shared preference or in a private application file (I store up to 100 local highscore entries, and 1000 all time scores and use files)